# NavigationView headerlayout not scrolling

Tags: android

I have simple question! I am stuck on it. I have seen plenty of answers and tried everything that I can.

Here is my `DrawerLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".BaseNavDrawerActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header_layout"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_text_color_selector"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_text_color_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is my `nav_drawer_header_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/drawer_cover">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/google_logo"
    android:id="@+id/image_account"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_accounts_list"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I scroll NavigationDrawer, only NavigationView get scrolled but headerlayout(`nav_drawer_header_layout`) remains still and doesn't scroll at all.

I know DrawerLayout scrolls completely but I am stuck here.

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT-1**

Java code snippet:

```
mNavViewHeaderLayout = LayoutInflater.from(EmailActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_header_layout, mNavigationView);
    mSpinnerAccounts = (Spinner)mNavViewHeaderLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner_accounts_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things.

1. remove `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header_layout"` from your NavigationView.
2. Inflate header in your navigation view at run time.

   View headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home);

   ```
   TextView txtContact = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtContact);

   TextView  txtHeaderLogoName = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtHeaderLogoName);
   ```

Comment: It has nothing to do with **Scrolling**.

Comment: when you add   app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header_layout" & app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer" in navigationView, then both part work as a separate layout. but when you inflate nav_header insteade of using it in xml. then they are termed as single view and both view scroll together.

Comment: I have many way to scroll nav_header with menu item, but it is the simplest one..just try it.. it will work

Comment: ohho.. You are not doing it in correct way.. you need to inflate header view like this View headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100350/discussion-between-faizan-mubasher-and-himanshu-shekher-jha).